# When save GORM entity in Micronaut Job an text field throws DataIntegrityViolationException... Data truncation: Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, hibernate, groovy, grails-orm, micronaut

I tried to save a GORM Entity in Micronaut Project Job:

Entity:

```
@Entity
class OutputProcess extends Process implements Serializable{

    static hasMany = [
            rows: StatusRow
    ]

    static mapping = {
        content type: 'text'
        info    type: 'text'
        rows lazy: false, cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    static constraints = {
        target       nullable: false
        status       nullable: false
        content      nullable: false
        contentId    nullable: true
        info         nullable: true
    }
}

class Process extends DomainBase{
    String target
    ProcessStatus status
    String info

    String content
    Long contentId
}

class DomainBase {
    Date dateCreated = new Date()
    Date lastUpdated = new Date()

    String createdBy = "system"
    String updatedBy = "system"
}
```

The stack of calls:

```
@Transactional
@Singleton
@Slf4j
class WorkerJob{
    @Inject ProcessService processService

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = "600s", initialDelay = "60s")
    void processPoints(){
        // ...
        processService.updateProcessList(outputProcessList)
    }
}

@Service(OutputProcess)
class ProcessService{
    List<OutputProcess> updateProcessList(List<OutputProcess> outputProcessList) {
        for ( OutputProcess outputProcess : outputProcessList ){
            outputProcess.markDirty()
            outputProcess.save(flush: true, failOnError:true)
        }
        return outputProcessList
    }
}
```

field 'info' value:

> Error while process SurveyAnswerRelation:
>   No signature of method: 
>   micronaut.foundation.service.answer.$AnswerRelationServiceImplementation.creditAnswerPoints() > is applicable for argument types: 
>   (micronaut.scrucovo5.foundation.domain.survey.Survey_$$_jvste31_8...) values: 
>   [micronaut.scrucovo5.foundation.domain.campaign.Activity : 1, ...]

MySql field 'info'

```
info longtext NULL
```

Error:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate operation: could not 
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'info' at row 1; 
>   nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for 
>   column 'info' at row 1

I tried many ways to save and they all give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I make a mistake, because there is a same column named 'info' in 'row' of StatusRow entity that is not typed 'text'